# How to remove a tag which name includes braces?

Tags: git

Show tags on remote

```
$ git ls-remote --tags origin
.....
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx refs/tags/v1.0.7^{}
.....
```

How to remove this tag?

I have tried:

```
$ git push --delete origin v1.0.7^{}
fatal: invalid refspec ':v1.0.7^{}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag name is `v1.0.7`.

When you use `git ls-remote`, Git shows you both the target object of the tag itself, and the more-base object to which the tag points.  If the tag is a lightweight tag, these two are by definition the same thing, and you see only one item:

```
04c6e9e9ca34226db095bbaa1218030f99f0b7c6    refs/tags/foo
```

When the tag is an *annotated* tag, however, the object to which it points is a an *annotated tag object*—it must be, by definition, since otherwise the tag would be a lightweight tag—and that annotated tag object has another underlying object.

The syntax for finding the underlying object is to suffix the tag name with `^{}`, as described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtemegemv0998em):

> ***<rev>^{}*, e.g. *v0.99.8^{}***
>   A suffix ^ followed by an empty brace pair means the object could be a tag, and dereference the tag recursively until a non-tag object is found.

Hence:

```
$ git rev-parse v2.21.0
2bb64867dc05d9a8432488ddc1d22a194cee4d31
$ git rev-parse v2.21.0^{}
8104ec994ea3849a968b4667d072fedd1e688642
```

and:

```
$ git show v2.21.0 | head -3 | sed 's/@/ /'
tag v2.21.0
Tagger: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
Date:   Sun Feb 24 07:55:39 2019 -0800
$ git show v2.21.0^{} | head -3 | sed 's/@/ /'
commit 8104ec994ea3849a968b4667d072fedd1e688642
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
Date:   Sun Feb 24 07:55:19 2019 -0800
```

Here `v2.21.0` is the tag.  That name identifies internal Git object `2bb64867dc05d9a8432488ddc1d22a194cee4d31` which is an annotated tag object:

```
$ git cat-file -t 2bb64867dc05d9a8432488ddc1d22a194cee4d31
tag
```

The tag object then goes on to identify the commit object `8104ec994ea3849a968b4667d072fedd1e688642`.  The output from `git ls-remote` therefore includes:

```
2bb64867dc05d9a8432488ddc1d22a194cee4d31        refs/tags/v2.21.0
8104ec994ea3849a968b4667d072fedd1e688642        refs/tags/v2.21.0^{}
```

The first is the tag; the second is the underlying commit.  The one tag name `v2.21.0` means *both* things, depending on how you ask Git about it.